# Perl regex to extract groups of digits from string of dot-separated integers

Tags: regex, perl

First off, I'm working with Perl 5.14.1.

I've been pulling my hair out over the following issue (NOTE: I absolutely **suck** at anything to do with regular expressions). I'm looking for a regular expression to extract only the numbers from strings such as the following:

```
E4.1
E6
e16
e6.7.3
E42.9
```

Basically, there's always an e (upper or lower case) followed by at least one group of digits. If there are multiple groups of digits, they are separated by a dot. What I want to do is to extract all groups of numbers into an array. For instance:

```
E4.1 -> ( 4, 1 )
E65 -> ( 65 )
e5.8.3 -> ( 5, 8, 3 )
```

where the stuff in parentheses is supposed to be the arrays of numbers I extracted from the strings.

What I got so far is

```
my @groupsOfNumbers = ( $inputString =~ /(\d+)((\.)\d+)*/g );
```

My reasoning here was, there's always at least one group of numbers (hence the first **(\d+)**), optionally followed by any number of dot-followed-by-digits groupings (hence the **((.)\d+)*** part). Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. For example, if I apply that regex to this input:

```
E4.3.1
```

the result is:

( "4", ".1", "." )

Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to bother with dot matching, as you want only numbers,

```
my @groupsOfNumbers = $inputString =~ /(\d+)/g;
```

Comment: Hi Flanker (love that plane)! ;-)

True, but I'd also like a minimal bit of validation, so that for instance the following string "e4_4_6_2" doesn't return any numbers at all.

EDIT: Well come to think of it, I can probably do without that. Your answer will do. Thanks!

Comment: I would go with non regex solution https://eval.in/174459 Yes, plain looks/behaves like work of art. :)